# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of Transformed Symmetric Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation, symmetry

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix, of the following form:
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & 0 \\ b & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Furthermore, let $B$ be the transformation of this matrix, using the transformation matrix $P$:
$$
B = P^TA P
$$
The matrix $P$ is invertible but not necessarily orthogonal, i.e. $P^{-1}\neq P^T$. (**Edit**: However, the last column of P is a unit vector, i.e. it has length one).

I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix $A$, but and I am interested in a relation with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix $B$. Since $P$ is not necessarily orthogonal, I cannot use *matrix similarity*, but I was thinking to use the Principle Axes Theorem, that states:

**Principle Axes Theorem**
Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. Then there is an orthogonal change of variable, $\mathbf{x}=P\mathbf{y}$, that transforms the quadratic form $\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}$ into a quadratic form $\mathbf{y}^TD\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{y}^T P^T A P\mathbf{y}$ with no cross-product term. The columns of $P$ are the *principle axes*.

So to repeat my question: is there a relation between the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and those of $B$?

Comment: I highly doubt that there’s any systematic relationship. Let’s say $\det A\ne0$ so that it can be interpreted as the matrix of a nondegenerate conic. If $P$ is invertible, then $P^TAP$ is the result of applying a homography (projective transformation) to the conic, but **all** nondegenerate conics are projectively equivalent—any nondegenerate conic can be transformed into any other via a homography.